# why every example that extends ArrayAdapter saves the list as private?

Tags: java, android

why in every example i see that extends the class ArrayAdapter it overrides the constructor that accepts T[] objects and references its own private variable to that and uses the referenced variable in the override of getView?
how can this be dynamic adding of objects?
will values be updated when a new item is added to the ArrayAdapter using add method?
can i instead of implementing my own adapter just use addheaderview in listview?

```
public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
  private final Context context;
  private final String[] values;
  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;
  }
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    textView.setText(values[position]);
    // change the icon for Windows and iPhone
    String s = values[position];
    if (s.startsWith("iPhone")) {
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no);
    } else {
      imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);
    }
    return rowView;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use the constructor which takes a list... and your adapter has an add() method...

Comment: but why save them in another different list? when i add new elements they wont be added to my list which in this case is values

Comment: You can create methods in your adapter to add new strings to the private list, and then call notifyDataSetChanged() to make the listView know that there is some new content to display

Comment: you are bypassing everything, it sounds like a patch

Comment: You dont need the values object, you can get your values you passed in the constructor via getItem()...